# How to determine the limit of a sequence in a metric space

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

If I'm trying to prove that a Metric space $(M,d)$ is not complete I have to find a Cauchy a sequence that doesn't converge in $M$.

Using the following Metric Space as an example:

> $M = \{  x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : ||x||<1 \}$
>
> $d(x,y) = 2-||x||-||y||$ if $x \neq y$, and $0$ otherwise

I know that the point $(1,1)$ lies outside this space, as $||(1,1)|| = \sqrt{2}  >1 $

So now I want to see if a sequence exists with this limit point.

I figured, in the usual metric the sequence $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{1}{n},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{1}{n}$ would converge to $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$

How would I check to see if the limit point is the same given the above metric $d$?

Or even better, how would I determine exactly what the limit of this sequence is given the above metric $d$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33985/discussion-on-question-by-gregory-peck-how-to-determine-the-limit-of-a-sequence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take for example the sequence $x_n = \left (1-\frac{1}{n},0\right )$
this sequence clearly belongs to $M$

Now in order to prove that the sequence is a Cauchy sequence we regard the distance between two terms of the sequence and show that the distance tends to $0$ as $n,m \to \infty$

$$d(x_n,x_m) = 2 - ||x_n|| - ||x_m|| = 2 - \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) - \left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)  = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m}  \longrightarrow 0 $$

After that, we should prove that the sequence not converges to any point, or more general, prove that there are not convergent sequences (showing  that the space is not complete) , this can be easily done just taking an arbitrary point $x$ and an arbitrary sequence $(x_n)$ and showing that $(x_n)$ can not converge to $x$ (take a look at the distance between $x$ and a general point of the sequence)

Comment: This was the very first sequence I looked at, as it was the easiest Cauchy sequence to find. So we are on similar wavelengths, great! But how do you show the sequence doesn't converge to a limit in $M$. (As it says in the title). This is something I've spent the last couple of hours trying to show. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I told you how to show that the sequence does not converge to any point of $M$. So did he. Let $x\in M$ and show that $d(x,x_n)$ does not tend to $0$. He _said_ you  should look at $d(x,x_n)$. Have you bothered to do that?